# How to include css font in Firefox and internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am using this css code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(http://localhost/mysite/css/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

to include some icons to my webpage. I found the original code in http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp, where for example

```
<div class="material-icons">menu</div>
```

generates a menu icon. The problem is, mypage only shows the menu icon in chrome and when I view it in firefox or IE, the menu icon doesn't show up and instead the word "menu" shows. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By only including woff2 you are only supporting the latest version of Chrome, Opera and Android browsers. It is **not** going to be viewable in Safari, Firefox, IE or iOS.

To ensure the broadest possible browser support you should include  all formats. Here is an example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot');
    src: local('Material Icons'),
         local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
         url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
         url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
         url(https://example.com/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype')
}
```

To learn more and to verify broswer support, visit either of the following resources:

- http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Where can I find other formats, the only format available is https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v7/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2

Comment: The latest stable version of all icons is available at https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases/download/2.0.0/material-design-icons-2.0.0.zip.

Individual icons are also available to download at https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Comment: Why the stable version size is about 57mb while the woff2 file is less than 1mb?